# Javascript fill dropdown from array and select some options

Tags: javascript, dropdown, selected

I want to select the Option where `month[i][2] = "1"`, there can be more than one selected.

```
function addOption_list() {
    var month = [["1", "January", ""], [["3", "Mars", ""], ["4", "April", ""], ["5", "May", ""], ["2", "February", "1"]]

    var select = document.getElementById('select_table');
    for (var i=0; i < month.length;++i){
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
            txt = document.createTextNode(month[i][1]);
        option.appendChild(txt);
        option.setAttribute("value",month[i][0]);
        if(month[i][2]!=''){
            // February need to be selected
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastchild);
        } else {
            // others not
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastchild);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add full code snippet!!!

Comment: What's your expected output and what output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `multiple` to the `select` element and then, when the condition is met for a given array entry, add attribute `selected` to the corresponding, newly created `option` like this `option.setAttribute('selected', true);`

```js
function addOption_list() {
    var month = [["1", "August", "1"], ["1", "January", ""], ["3", "Mars", ""], ["4", "April", ""], ["5", "May", ""], ["2", "February", "1"]];

    var select = document.getElementById('select_table');
    for (var i=0; i < month.length;++i){
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
            txt = document.createTextNode(month[i][1]);
        option.appendChild(txt);
        option.setAttribute("value", month[i][0]);
        if(month[i][2] === '1'){
            option.setAttribute('selected', true);
            select.insertBefore(option, select.lastchild);
        } else {
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastchild);
        }
    }
}

addOption_list();
```

```html
<select multiple id="select_table"></select>
```

When you run the snippet you will see two items selected because I have added `["1", "August", "1"]` to the list.

And you can change your code a little bit to make it more readable like this.

```js
function addOption_list() {
  const month = [["1", "August", "1"], ["1", "January", ""], ["3", "Mars", ""], ["4", "April", ""], ["5", "May", ""], ["2", "February", "1"]];
  const select = document.getElementById('select_table');

  month.forEach(mnth => {
    const option = document.createElement('OPTION');
    option.textContent = mnth[1];
    if (mnth[2] === '1') { option.setAttribute('selected', true) };
    select.append(option);
  });
}

addOption_list();
```

```html
<select multiple id="select_table"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. I just added option.setAttribute("value", mnth[0]); after option.textContent = mnth[1]; in the more readable code to add the value of the option.